# trying to overwrite '*', which is also in package faenza-icon-theme 0.8

Tags: dpkg

I have Docky installed on Ubuntu 10.10 64bit and noticed after a recent upgrade my 'Helpers' are no longer available. After some research I found that Dockmanager is no longer installed either.

I am unable to install it via the Software centre or via terminal using apt-get, the following error is returned;

```
mark@Sonata:~$ sudo apt-get install dockmanager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dockmanager
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/94.4kB of archives.
After this operation, 430kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 162015 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dockmanager (from .../dockmanager_0.1.0~bzr83-0ubuntu1~10.10~dockers1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/dockmanager_0.1.0~bzr83-0ubuntu1~10.10~dockers1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/dockmanager/data/skype_invisible.svg', which is also in package faenza-icon-theme 0.8
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dockmanager_0.1.0~bzr83-0ubuntu1~10.10~dockers1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
mark@Sonata:~$
```

Can anyone advise on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I'm unable to purge the Faenza package and when I try to remove it with the software center or Synaptic, I get an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely remove elementary OS (Ubuntu 18.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085041/how-to-completely-remove-elementary-os-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happened is that when you updated, it tried to install an update of the dockmanager, but a theme package you installed previously has done naughty things and replaced one of the dockmanager's files.

To fix you need to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge faenza-icon-theme
```

Then try and reinstall your dockmanager, you also need to report to the maintainer of `faenza-icon-theme` that he's made a broken package and he should fix it as soon as possible. Basically he needs to make it so that it doesn't replace files from other packages.

Comment: Can you +1 my question (press the little up arrow).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is:

```
sudo apt-get remove dockmanager
sudo apt-get purge faenza-icon-theme
sudo apt-get install dockmanager faenza-icon-theme
```

Comment: sudo apt-get purge faenza-icon-theme E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) command to remove Faenza don't work