# Broken package error after updating

Tags: package-management, synaptic

I updated my system using the Update Manager and now I am getting a "Broken Package" error.

I went into Synaptic Package Manager and clicked on *Fix Broken Packages* but then I got this error:

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/dockmanager_0.1.0~bzr80-0ubuntu1~10.10~dockers1_i386.deb:
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/dockmanager/data/skype_away.svg', which is also in package faenza-icon-theme 0.8
```

I cannot install or remove anything until the broken package is fixed. What should I do now?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested in the answers, I ran the commands

```
sudo apt-get purge faenza-icon-theme
sudo apt-get -f install
```

But still get the same error, here is what I get:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/565877/

**UPDATE 2:**

Fixed using http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html

Comment: If you get the solution then please mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...And here is the fix -- http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html

Comment: While this link may theoretically answer the question, it is best to include the essential parts of the answer here in case that link disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Exact duplicate of my error [trying to overwrite '*', which is also in package faenza-icon-theme 0.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20568/unable-to-install-dockmanager)

Follow the same steps and you should have no issue.

I sent an email to the package manager of Faenza icons about this but received no answer...

Comment: Didn't fix mine.

Comment: Faenza writes icons in some folders outside its icons folder ... and it shouldn't. For this reason, many things like this happen - the same with RadioTray and other apps. Use --force-all as suggested above when that happens and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the faenza-icon-theme package:

```
sudo apt-get purge faenza-icon-theme
```

Now, try to reinstall the dockmanager.

You can also try to run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Still getting the same error http://paste.ubuntu.com/565877/

Answer (score 0):

Faenza replaces some of the icons in order to integrate certain programs into the theme. To install this you'll have to overwrite.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite var/apt/cache/archives/dockmanager_0.1.0~bzr80-0ubuntu1~10.10~dockers1_i386.deb
```

You can also use `--force-all` instead of `--force-overwrite`

One thing I'm not sure about is the fact that you need to purge `faenza-extra` not `faenza-icon-theme`