# How to completely remove elementary OS (Ubuntu 18.04)?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, uninstall, elementary

So, I installed Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome3 and then lured by the prettiness of elementary OS 5.0, I installed that as per the instructions. Now, I have purged all the PPAs as suggested by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631023/how-to-completely-remove-elementary-desktop-from-ubuntu-14-04) or other answers here. However, I still get elementary os screen at the boot and when I see the `about` in gnome UI.

Cosmetics is not much of a problem for me but when I am trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10, I am not receiving any update when I do `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` or `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

How do I completely restore my gnome? or more directly How do I move to 18.10?

Output of `dpkg -l | grep -i elementary` is

```
ii  base-files                                      10.1ubuntu2.3+elementary12~ubuntu18.04.1       amd64        Debian base system miscellaneous files
ii  bash                                            4.4.18-2ubuntu1+elementary3~ubuntu5.0.1        amd64        GNU Bourne Again SHell
ii  browser-plugin-evince                           3.28.2-1+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1               amd64        plugin for web browsers to display documents (PostScript, PDF, …)
ii  desktop-file-utils                              0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1  amd64        Utilities for .desktop files
rc  elementary-default-settings                     5.0-0~304~ubuntu5.0.1                          all          Default settings for elementary OS
rc  elementary-icon-theme                           4.4.0+r2076~ubuntu5.0.1                        all          simple and appealing Tango-styled icon theme
ii  epiphany-browser                                3.28.1-1ubuntu1+elementary20~ubuntu5.0.1       amd64        Intuitive GNOME web browser
ii  epiphany-browser-data                           3.28.1-1ubuntu1+elementary20~ubuntu5.0.1       all          Data files for the GNOME web browser
ii  evince                                          3.28.2-1+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1               amd64        Document (PostScript, PDF) viewer
ii  evince-common                                   3.28.2-1+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1               all          Document (PostScript, PDF) viewer - common files
ii  file-roller                                     3.28.0-1ubuntu1+elementary4~ubuntu5.0.1        amd64        archive manager for GNOME
rc  fonts-croscore-config-elementary                5.0-0+33~ubuntu5.0.1                           all          Map open-source Croscore fonts to MS fonts
ii  geoclue-2.0                                     2.4.7-1ubuntu1+elementary2+r2~ubuntu5.0.1      amd64        geoinformation service
ii  gir1.2-evince-3.0:amd64                         3.28.2-1+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1               amd64        GObject introspection data for the evince libraries
ii  gir1.2-geoclue-2.0:amd64                        2.4.7-1ubuntu1+elementary2+r2~ubuntu5.0.1      amd64        convenience library to interact with geoinformation service (introspection)
ii  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0:amd64                 3.28.0-2+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1               amd64        Introspection data for GnomeBluetooth
ii  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0:amd64                      3.24.7-1+elementary5~ubuntu5.0.1               amd64        gir files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64                           1.5.17-3ubuntu4+elementary2+r1~ubuntu5.0.1     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - introspection data
ii  gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0:amd64                          1.8.10-2ubuntu1+elementary2~ubuntu18.04.1      amd64        GObject introspection data for libnm-gtk
ii  gnome-settings-daemon                           3.28.1-0ubuntu1+elementary3~ubuntu5.0.1        amd64        daemon handling the GNOME session settings
ii  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas                   3.28.1-0ubuntu1+elementary3~ubuntu5.0.1        all          Shared schemas for gnome-settings-daemon
ii  ibus                                            1.5.17-3ubuntu4+elementary2+r1~ubuntu5.0.1     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - core
ii  ibus-gtk:amd64                                  1.5.17-3ubuntu4+elementary2+r1~ubuntu5.0.1     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - GTK+2 support
ii  ibus-gtk3:amd64                                 1.5.17-3ubuntu4+elementary2+r1~ubuntu5.0.1     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - GTK+3 support
rc  io.elementary.cerbere                           0.2.4+r70-0+pkg30~ubuntu5.0.1                  amd64        service to relaunch Pantheon shell components
rc  io.elementary.dpms-helper                       1.0+r8+pkg11~ubuntu5.0.1                       all          script and settings for X DPMS
ii  language-selector-common                        0.188.1+elementary4~ubuntu18.04.1              all          Language selector for Ubuntu
ii  language-selector-gnome                         0.188.1+elementary4~ubuntu18.04.1              all          Language selector for Ubuntu
ii  libevdocument3-4:amd64                          3.28.2-1+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1               amd64        Document (PostScript, PDF) rendering library
ii  libevview3-3:amd64                              3.28.2-1+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1               amd64        Document (PostScript, PDF) rendering library - Gtk+ widgets
ii  libgeoclue-2-0:amd64                            2.4.7-1ubuntu1+elementary2+r2~ubuntu5.0.1      amd64        convenience library to interact with geoinformation service
ii  libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64                      3.28.0-2+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1               amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library
ii  libgtksourceview-3.0-1:amd64                    3.24.7-1+elementary5~ubuntu5.0.1               amd64        shared libraries for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libgtksourceview-3.0-common                     3.24.7-1+elementary5~ubuntu5.0.1               all          common files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libibus-1.0-5:amd64                             1.5.17-3ubuntu4+elementary2+r1~ubuntu5.0.1     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - shared library
ii  libibus-1.0-dev:amd64                           1.5.17-3ubuntu4+elementary2+r1~ubuntu5.0.1     amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - development file
ii  libnm-gtk0:amd64                                1.8.10-2ubuntu1+elementary2~ubuntu18.04.1      amd64        library for wireless and mobile dialogs (libnm-glib version)
ii  libnma0:amd64                                   1.8.10-2ubuntu1+elementary2~ubuntu18.04.1      amd64        library for wireless and mobile dialogs (libnm version)
ii  lsb-base                                        9.20170808ubuntu1+elementary4~ubuntu18.04.1    all          Linux Standard Base init script functionality
ii  lsb-release                                     9.20170808ubuntu1+elementary4~ubuntu18.04.1    all          Linux Standard Base version reporting utility
ii  mutter-common                                   3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1+elementary3~ubuntu5.0.1 all          shared files for the Mutter window manager
ii  network-manager-gnome                           1.8.10-2ubuntu1+elementary2~ubuntu18.04.1      amd64        network management framework (GNOME frontend)
rc  plank                                           0.11.4+git20180707.0a842b45-0elementary0.5.1   amd64        Elegant, simple, clean dock
ii  python-apt-common                               1.6.2+elementary6~ubuntu5.0.1                  all          Python interface to libapt-pkg (locales)
ii  python3-apt                                     1.6.2+elementary6~ubuntu5.0.1                  amd64        Python 3 interface to libapt-pkg
ii  python3-cupshelpers                             1.5.11-1ubuntu2+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1        all          Python utility modules around the CUPS printing system
ii  python3-software-properties                     0.96.24.32.5+elementary7~ubuntu18.04.1         all          manage the repositories that you install software from
ii  software-properties-common                      0.96.24.32.5+elementary7~ubuntu18.04.1         all          manage the repositories that you install software from (common)
ii  software-properties-gtk                         0.96.24.32.5+elementary7~ubuntu18.04.1         all          manage the repositories that you install software from (gtk)
ii  system-config-printer                           1.5.11-1ubuntu2+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1        all          graphical interface to configure the printing system
ii  system-config-printer-common                    1.5.11-1ubuntu2+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1        all          backend and the translation files for system-config-printer
ii  system-config-printer-gnome                     1.5.11-1ubuntu2+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1        all          graphical interface to configure printers (transitional package)
ii  system-config-printer-udev                      1.5.11-1ubuntu2+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1        amd64        Utilities to detect and configure printers automatically
rc  unattended-upgrades                             1.1ubuntu1.18.04.5+elementary5~ubuntu5.0.1     all          automatic installation of security upgrades
ii  xdg-user-dirs                                   0.17-1ubuntu1+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1          amd64        tool to manage well known user directories
ii  xdg-user-dirs-gtk                               0.10-2+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1                 amd64        tool to manage well known user directories (Gtk extension)
```

Comment: Hint: Why are you using the '-d' flag?

Comment: with or w/o -d flag.. outcome is same

Comment: `-d` flag shows you the versions which are available but in development stage while the other will show the latest stable update. I believe that you have opted for **LTS updates only** which means 18.10 won't be delivered to you. You can confirm it from `Software and Updates` app. Also, have you tried reinstalling or re-configuring GNOME?

Comment: I did uninstall gnome-shell and reinstalled. Also, I have opted for notifying of any new update and not only lts

Comment: Try reinstalling `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` instead of only gnome-shell. Also, it is suggested to stick to LTS unless and until it is required to move to non-LTS.

Comment: People suggesting not to move to non-LTS. I know the ups and downs, have been using linux based os since 11.04. I just want to know why I am not getting upgrades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is bad idea do upgrade from LTS to non-LTS version. You will need to wait for 20.04 LTS with all possible stops as 19.04 and 19.10. Consider to stay on 18.04 LTS.**

If you have added elementary by PPAs, then you can remove them with commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/testing
```

then reinstall GNOME Shell with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

---

As we have the output of `dpkg -l | grep -i elementary` then I can suggest two things:

1. Purge remaining packages with `rc` state (with remaining config files):

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep -i elementary | grep ^rc | awk '{print $2}')
```

2. Reinstall packages with *elementary* versions from current repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep -i elementary | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Nope! doesn't work. Purged & reinstalled. Didnt work

Comment: Then please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i elementary` to your question.

Comment: Thanks for paying attention to this question. I have updated the question with output and I sort of understand what is happening but how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Updated answer. Please carefully follow the last part.

Comment: This ideally works that why I accepted the answer. However, this bricked my OS. As uninstalling `lsb` related packages led to uninstallation of everything

Comment: Forgot to mention that is was very dangerous operation. But you still can fix the whole system by installing desktop back with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: yeah if only wifi (network) had worked. Currently fixing that with a recovery disk