# How to completely remove Elementary OS 5.0 Juno from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, elementary

I have found similar topics, but none of the answers helped me.

I have installed Elementary, but the amount of bugs on it was atrocious, so I wanted to move back to just regular Ubuntu (Yeah, I know they have the same kernel and what not- but on Elementary things like the clock, wifi  aren't working and they were working perfectly before). I managed to get my log on screen back to Ubuntu and delete all the apps, but I still have the KUBUNTU screen when turning on the laptop and have the Elementary in the settings as my system.

Comment: How about a clean install of Ubuntu?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1085156/66509 .

Comment: N0rbert, I tried that. Have none of the PPAs and Ubuntu is already installed.

Comment: @francescop21, I would prefer not to, if there are other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove Elementary from Sessions to prevent it to list while turning on your system.

```
cd /usr/share/xsessions
sudo rm -f elementary.desktop kubuntu.desktop
```